# Running meld: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append_search_path'

Tags: macos, x11

After upgrading to Mountain Lion 10.8.5 I can no longer run `meld` via X11. I get the following. I've tried searching around for solutions but found nothing that works.

```
$ meld
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:57: GtkWarning: could not open display
  warnings.warn(str(e), _gtk.Warning)
/opt/local/bin/meld:111: GtkWarning: gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
  gtk.icon_theme_get_default().append_search_path(meld.paths.icon_dir())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/local/bin/meld", line 111, in <module>
    gtk.icon_theme_get_default().append_search_path(meld.paths.icon_dir())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append_search_path'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After finally stumbling upon this https://trac.macports.org/ticket/35697, I installed XQuartz to replace X11 and restarted. `meld` now works